# 'arara' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: arara, atom

I'm trying to compile my .tex file using Atom editor and arara. I switched from my office computer to my personal one, installed atom and TexLive and I obtain the following error:

```
Command failed: arara IEEE_Flyback_aux_supply -v
'arara' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What does this error mean and is there a remedy for it?

Comment: Which operating stystem? Is your Atom editor able to run pdfLaTeX? If so is LaTeX configured somewhere, for example using full path to pdfLaTeX.